# inner elements remains invisible after a css3 transition

Tags: google-chrome, css, css-transitions

After a css3 transition being done, a callback makes the inner elements to be visible (using universal selector and opacity property).

In the following case, they stay invisible from the screen. The strangest thing is that when using the console and "inspect the element", they magically appear.

http://jsfiddle.net/tT84s/12/

This bug happens on Chrome 19.0.1084.52 but not on Safari 5.1.5

I'm suspecting a rendering bug, some internal browser triggers which doesn't fire or something like that.

Comment: So when I click the button once, the red border flys out, then I need to click it again for the content to come out. Are you trying to have the transition and the visibility both fire at the same time?

Comment: Since the text won't scale the size of the box, I'd like to have it appear after the red box has finished it's transition. the needed steps are :
 1/ red box goes to 100% height and width
 2/ the end of the transition is caught, and launch the next one
 3/ inner text appears

It seems to works, but the content stays hidden until the element is inspected through the console. It's even selectable with the mouse but still invisible.

Comment: This in interesting - it works on Firefox too, so I guess it's most likely a bug in Google Chrome.

Comment: I guess so. A bug issue has been filled https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=130081

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try http://jsfiddle.net/tT84s/13/

Shaking the DOM seems to work. In this fiddle, I re-append the transitioning element's children (in the same order they were originally positioned). It seems to work in the fiddle -  though some solutions mentioned here didn't work for our specific experience of this bug.

Generally speaking, it looks like forcing a DOM change works. Note, however that inserting and removing a `<div>` had no effect. Go figure! Good luck, and everyone please try to post your working solutions for this or related fiddles/bug-demonstrations. For example, this may work with simply adding and removing the last child - to avoid doing more appendChild actions than necessary.

Answer (score 1):

`-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden`

Webkit Bug. Try using the code above, it may help with your problem. Also you might want to use `transform: scale()` instead of  width and height.